# Как рисовать на объектах ( кнопка, поле ввода и так далее ) с помощью GDI+?

Tags: c++, gdi+

Необходимо изменить визуальное оформление некоторых объектов которые создаются при помощи CreateWindowEx. Изменить цвет фона, цвет текста, шрифт и так далее. Слышал что можно сделать это при помощи обработки сообщения отрисовки и перерисовыванию нужного при помощи GDI+, но что нужно конкретно делать не понимаю.

Я создал форму с помощью CreateWindowExA, затем в WM_CREATE создаю кнопку. Как изменить цвет её фона?

[image: Изображение]

Comment: Это очень расплывчатый вопрос. Разные виджеты предоставляют разные возможности для настройки внешнего вида. Рисование всего самостоятельно - это скорее крайний вариант. Ну и как и в прошлом вопросе - следует использовать исключительно функции с суффиксом W.

Comment: Я не понимаю почему нужно использовать именно W вместо A. Вы не могли бы пожалуйста объяснить в чём разница?

Comment: Это legacy API, которое осталось со времен, когда в Windows не было поддержки юникода. Уже начиная где-то с Windows 2000 от его использования будет только дополнительный оверхед и собственно отсутствие поддержки юникода. Ну а многие относительно свежие API вообще не имеют A вариантов.

Comment: Мне наоборот использование A нравилось тем что там не нужно было писать L"блабла".. По моему это намного удобнее.. Странно что так.

Comment: Пожалуйста, Вы не могли бы мне подсказать, как правильно перенести создание формы с CreateWindowA на CreateWindowW? Я попробовал заменить везде A на W и добавить L, но почему-то в заголовке отображается только один, первый символ. Вот скриншот: https://i.imgur.com/eCyOkOy.png

Comment: @user7860670 Пожалуйста :(

Comment: я не знаю, на вид вроде оно нормально написано, для такого рода вопросов нужен [mcve]

Comment: Я извиняюсь, была ошибка в том что я не поменял DefWindowProcA на W